# superset server not running

Tags: apache-superset

I am following the below instructions to install superset. In this step "superset runserver -d" getting an error below. How do I fix this issue. Thanks

[DEPRECATED] As of Flask >=1.0.0, this command is no longer supported, please use `flask run` instead, as documented in our CONTRIBUTING.md
[example]
flask run -p 8080 --with-threads --reload --debugger

```
# Install superset
pip install superset

# Create an admin user (you will be prompted to set a username, first and last name before setting a password)
fabmanager create-admin --app superset

# Initialize the database
superset db upgrade

# Load some data to play with
superset load_examples

# Create default roles and permissions
superset init

# To start a development web server on port 8088, use -p to bind to another port
superset runserver -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday commit https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/5966 fixed similiar issue with docker install. Try to clone repo from scratch and go trough the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/
cd incubator-superset/contrib/docker
# prefix with SUPERSET_LOAD_EXAMPLES=yes to load examples:
docker-compose run --rm superset ./docker-init.sh
# you can run this command everytime you need to start superset now:
docker-compose up
```

New installation doc: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/docs/installation.rst

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps:

```sh
$ pip install flask==1.0.0
$ pip install sqlalchemy==1.2.18
$ pip uninstall pandas
$ pip install pandas==0.23.4
```